# JSplitPane only show real weight in current tab inside JTabbedPane inside a Jframe at the time of its creation

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, jsplitpane

This is my main class with

Class MainGuiFrame:

```
public class MainGuiFrame extends JFrame {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            MainGuiFrame jf;
            try {
                jf = new MainGuiFrame();
                setLookAndFeel();
                jf.setVisible(true);
                jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}







private JSplitPane jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions;
private FileReadAndRunJpnl jpnlInputFile;
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

private final int widthCarMapAndButtons=650, heightCarMapAndButtons = 620;
private final int widthJpnlFunctions=650, heightJpnlFunctions=60;//+heightJpnlMapButtons;
private CarsDrawingJpnl jpnlCarDeckDrawing;
private CarsDrawingJpnl jpnlPlatformDeckDrawing;
private CarsDrawingJpnl jpnlTrailerDeckDrawing;


public MainGuiFrame() throws IOException {

    super( "Ferry Visualization");                      // invoke the JFrame constructor
    setSize(new Dimension(650,700));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(650,700));
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());//getContentPane().



    //TABBED PANE
    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthCarMapAndButtons,heightCarMapAndButtons));
    jpnlCarDeckDrawing = new CarsDrawingJpnl(widthCarMapAndButtons,heightCarMapAndButtons);
    jpnlPlatformDeckDrawing = new CarsDrawingJpnl(widthCarMapAndButtons,heightCarMapAndButtons);
    jpnlTrailerDeckDrawing = new CarsDrawingJpnl(widthCarMapAndButtons,heightCarMapAndButtons);


    tabbedPane.add(jpnlCarDeckDrawing);
    Dimension tabbedPaneTabSize= new Dimension(150,30);   
    JLabel labCarDeck = new JLabel("Car Deck");
    labCarDeck.setFont(labCarDeck.getFont().deriveFont (20.0f).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));

    labCarDeck.setPreferredSize(tabbedPaneTabSize);
    tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, labCarDeck);  // tab index, jLabel


    tabbedPane.add(jpnlPlatformDeckDrawing);
    JLabel labPlatformDeck = new JLabel("Platform Deck");
    labPlatformDeck.setFont(labPlatformDeck.getFont().deriveFont (20.0f).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));

    labPlatformDeck.setPreferredSize(tabbedPaneTabSize);
    tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(1, labPlatformDeck);  // tab index, jLabel


    tabbedPane.add(jpnlTrailerDeckDrawing);
    JLabel labTrailerDeck = new JLabel("Trailer Deck");
    labTrailerDeck.setFont(labTrailerDeck.getFont ().deriveFont (20.0f).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));

    labTrailerDeck.setPreferredSize(tabbedPaneTabSize);
    tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(2, labTrailerDeck);  // tab index, jLabel


    tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(2);





    jpnlInputFile = new FileReadAndRunJpnl(widthJpnlFunctions, heightJpnlFunctions);
    //jpnlInputFile.openInputDirectTest();

    //SPLIT BETWEEN MAP AND ALL FUNCTION BELOW
    Border borScrollPane = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();

    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions= new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.setBorder(borScrollPane);
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthCarMapAndButtons,heightCarMapAndButtons));
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.setResizeWeight(0.90);
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.setDividerSize(5);
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.add(tabbedPane);
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.add(jpnlInputFile);









add(jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions, BorderLayout.CENTER);// getContentPane().


}
```

The class CarsDrawingJpnl is a JPanel which contain a drawing area(JPanel) and corresponding buttons(JPanel)

Class CarsDrawingJpnl:

```
public class CarsDrawingJpnl extends JPanel {

private CarsDrawingMap jpnlCarsMap;
private CarMapButtons jpnlCarMapCounterButtons;

private JScrollPane carDrawingScroller;
private JSplitPane jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions;


private TwoJourneyModel twoJourneyCustomers;




public CarsDrawingJpnl(int width , int height) {


    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));//this is neccesary for the component to realize the size in practicality given in constructor
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Border borScrollPane = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
    this.setBorder(borScrollPane);
    //CAR MAP

    int widthJpnlMapButtons=width, heightJpnlMapButtons=height/6;

    int widthCarMap=width, heightCarMap = height-heightJpnlMapButtons;
    jpnlCarsMap = new CarsDrawingMap(this,widthCarMap,heightCarMap);

    carDrawingScroller = new JScrollPane( jpnlCarsMap);

    carDrawingScroller.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(5);
    carDrawingScroller.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,5));
    carDrawingScroller.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(7);
    carDrawingScroller.getHorizontalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5,30));
    carDrawingScroller.setBorder(borScrollPane);


    jpnlCarMapCounterButtons= new CarMapButtons(this,widthJpnlMapButtons, heightJpnlMapButtons);
    DisabledPanel.disable(jpnlCarMapCounterButtons);

    //SPLIT BETWEEN MAP AND ALL FUNCTION BELOW
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions= new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
//  jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.setDividerLocation(0.5);
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.setResizeWeight(0.70);
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.setDividerSize(5);
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.add(carDrawingScroller);
    jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions.add(jpnlCarMapCounterButtons);


    this.add(jSplitPaneMapPlusFunctions, BorderLayout.CENTER);



}
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

When i run my main class the size of split pane used in Class CarsDrawingJpnl is updated only in the current tab at the start of running the program as shown in the picture below.

The current tab at the time of running the main JFrame Class:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge6ra.jpg]

While the other tabs dont show the real weightage of JSplitPane while the three of the tabs are object of the same class and instantiated in the same of way.The other tab can be seen in the picture below.

The non current tab at the time of running the main JFrame Class:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfA8i.jpg]

Whichever tab i select at the time of running the main class show updated weightage while the rest dont show that.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, but the LAF should be set BEFORE you create any Swing components.

Comment: the jsplitpane does not behave the same way for three similar tabs. It applies the weightage to current tab at the time of running the program. The irregular behaviour is shown in the disabled panels in the two pictures shown.(The buttons are smaller in one as compared to the other picture)